# How do I output an equal sign (=) as the text content of a HTML tag in a slim template?

Tags: slim-lang

When writing a slim template, I can't get an equal sign (=) to show up in the output, for instance when I write

```
a.btn class=["btn-lg", "col-xs-2"] This works
```

I see the output

```
<a class="btn btn-lg col-xs-2">This works</a>
```

However, when I write

```
a.btn class=["btn-lg", "col-xs-2"] =
```

the output doesn't display the equal sign

```
<a class="btn btn-lg col-xs-2"></a>
```

Does anyone know how to get slim to output the equal sign as the text content of an HTML tag?

Answer (score 0):

> The equals sign tells Slim it's a Ruby call.

View more in [Slim readme](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#output-)

So with = you are setting the content of your tag to what comes after = , in this case nothing (it's similar to setting it to `nil`).

You can have the equals sign as a string like this:

```
a.btn class=["btn-lg", "col-xs-2"] = "="
```

or this:

```
a.btn class=["btn-lg", "col-xs-2"]
  | =
```